# Implicit conversion in monadic for comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, implicit-conversion, for-comprehension, implicits

Say I have the following functions:

```
case class ErrA(msg: String)

case class ErrB(msg: String)

def doA(): Either[ErrA, Int] = Right(2)

def doB(): Either[ErrB, Int] = Right(3)
```

`ErrA` and `ErrB` are unrelated types and are not actually declared in the same file outside of this example. They cannot be easily made to inherit from a common type.

I would like to introduce a new type that would represent both error types:

```
sealed trait ErrAOrB

case class ErrAWrapper(e: ErrA) extends ErrAOrB

case class ErrBWrapper(e: ErrB) extends ErrAOrB
```

And then write the following function using a for comprehension:

```
def doAplusB(): Either[ErrAOrB, Int] =
  for (a <- doA().right;
       b <- doB().right) yield a + b
```

Is there any way to get the compiler to implicitly convert those specific `Either` types to the common `Either[ErrAOrB, Int]` type?

For instance:

```
implicit def wrapA[T](res: Either[ErrA, T]): Either[ErrAOrB, T] = res.left.map(ErrAWrapper(_))

implicit def wrapB[T](res: Either[ErrB, T]): Either[ErrAOrB, T] = res.left.map(ErrBWrapper(_))
```

But that doesn't work because the implicit conversion gets applied only to the final expression in the for comprehension, and then the compiler has to bind it to `doA` and since types `ErrA` and `ErrAOrB` are unrelated the best it can do is to make the generics make sense is to use `Object` which is not compatible with the expected type.

Comment: just to note that implicit views are not recommended in Scala - use implicit class instead, so it could be smthng like `doA().right.wrap`. Just imagine people reading your code and wondering about how did `Either[ErrA, Int]` became `ErrAOrB`? No IDE hint, so no good way to find your `wrapA` implicits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit views are not recommended in Scala, as you can see from compiler's feature warning when you define `wrapA`/`wrapB`.

Even if you take your chances by defining implicit view over `Either.RightProjection` instead `Either` - Just imagine people reading your code and wondering about how did `Either[ErrA, Int]` become `Either[ErrAOrB, Int]`? No IDE hint, so no good way to find your wrapA implicits

So, use implicit class instead:

```
implicit class WrapA[T](x: Either[ErrA, T]) {
  def wrap = x.left.map(ErrAWrapper(_)): Either[ErrAOrB, T]
}

implicit class WrapB[T](x: Either[ErrB, T]) {
  def wrap = x.left.map(ErrBWrapper(_)): Either[ErrAOrB, T]
}

scala> def doAplusB(): Either[ErrAOrB, Int] =
     |   for {
     |      a <- doA().wrap.right
     |      b <- doB().wrap.right
     |   } yield a + b
doAplusB: ()Either[ErrAOrB,Int]
```

P.S. You don't need monad for `+` operation if your computations are independent (like in your example) - Applicative is enough. Take a look at cats.data.Validated or scalaz.Validation for instance.

---

Answering wether it's possible or not to trick scalac:

```
implicit def wrapBB[T](res: Either.RightProjection[ErrB, T]): Either.RightProjection[ErrAOrB, T] = res.e.left.map(ErrBWrapper(_)).right

implicit def wrapAA[T](res: Either.RightProjection[ErrA, T]): Either.RightProjection[ErrAOrB, T] = res.e.left.map(ErrAWrapper(_)).right

def doAplusB(): Either[ErrAOrB, Int] =
  for (a <- doA().right: Either.RightProjection[ErrAOrB, Int] ;
       b <- doB().right: Either.RightProjection[ErrAOrB, Int]) yield a + b
```

But this requires `Either.RightProjection` type ascription, but if you had some parallel assignment (Applicative-style instead of for-comprehension), I believe the thing with ad-hoc supertype could work.

Or even (with your `wrapB` defined):

```
implicit def wrapAA[T] ...
implicit def wrapBB[T] ...

implicit def wrapB[T](res: Either[ErrB, T]): Either[ErrAOrB, T] = res.left.map(ErrBWrapper(_))

def doAplusB(): Either[ErrAOrB, Int] =
  for (a <- doA().right:  Either.RightProjection[ErrAOrB, Int];
       b <- doB().right) yield a + b
```

The reason is an expansion to:

```
doA().right.flatMap(a => doB().right.map(b => a + b))
```

`flatMap` requires `RightProjection` to be returned, but `map` doesn't.

Comment: I completely agree that explicit is better than implicit, I was just curious if it was possible to abuse the implicits to achieve this without any explicit conversions at all. The actual operations are dependent on each other.